# Content pane in dojo

Tags: javascript, dojo, contentpane

I have a content pane (B) that is created when I click a button which is inside another content pane( A) in tab container.

In B I have used closeable to true and also on close function .now when I close B it is working fine but  my requirement is that if I click button in A , B should be created again how I can do this .I have tried by assigning null to content pane variable in on close function so that new content pane is created again but giving error  can not read property of null owner document

Comment: where is your code ? could you post what have you tried here ?

Comment: tabcontainer tc  in which created contentpane (cp) .In this cp (tab8) have created a button with label Show Layer List when click button a new cp is created in which closable is set to true.now my requirement is when closable is clicked it should be closed  than again showlayerlist is clicked same cp or new cp is to be shown   tab8=new ContentPane({title:"Legend",id:"legendid"
});tc.addChild( tab8 );
tab8.addChild( new dijit.form.Button({"label": "Show Layer List",id:"LayerListBtn",
  onClick: function(){
     showLayerListFunction( layerList, LayerList, defineActions, dom); 
  }
}));

Comment: can you edit the question and post the whole code , otherwise we can't help !

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is inside `showLayerListFunction` ,

See below example in which your can recreate tab after its deletion

```js
require(["dojo/on", "dojo/dom", "dojo/ready", "dijit/registry","dojo/dom-construct", "dijit/layout/TabContainer", "dijit/layout/ContentPane", "dijit/form/Button",
  "dojo/dom-style"
], function(On, dom, ready, registry,domConstruct, TabContainer, ContentPane,  Button, domStyle) {
  ready(function() {
    var tabContainer = registry.byId("center");
    var tab1 = registry.byId("tab1");
    
    var btn = registry.byId("show");
    var tab2;
    btn.on("click", function(e){
      // if pane exist skip creation 
      if(!registry.byId("legendid")) {
        tab2 = new ContentPane({title:"List",id:"legendid",closable:true });
        tabContainer.addChild(tab2);
        
      }
tabContainer.selectChild(tab2);
    })
    
  });
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

#center {
  height: 100% !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.0/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script>
  dojoConfig = {
    parseOnLoad: true,
    async: true
  };
</script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.0/dojo/dojo.js"></script>

<body class="claro">
  <div id="center" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/TabContainer" >
<div id="tab1" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane"  title="tab1">
  <div data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" id="show"> Show Layer List</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: thanks for response  i am getting below error 
  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'ownerDocument') btn.on("click",function(e){
  if(!registry.byId("layerListID")){
  var tab2= new ContentPane({
      title: "Layers", id: "layerListID",
      closable: true,
      onShow: function () {
        if (layerList === undefined) {
          layerList = new LayerList({
            view: view,
            listItemCreatedFunction: defineActions
          }, dom.byId("layerListID"));
        };
      }
    }, "layers"); tc.addChild(tab2); tc.selectChild(tab2);
  }